How To Find Missing Dependency in Cargo.toml for Rust Example
I am trying to learn Rust programming, and working with the Github example named "about_dialog" for gtk4. I currently have a Cargo.toml file with the following:
name = "AboutDialog"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
cairo-sys-rs = "0.20.0"
gdk = "0.18.0"
gdk4 = "0.9.0"
glib = "0.20.0"
gtk = "0.18.1"
gtk4 = "0.9.0"

When invoking "cargo build", a portion of the following error is displayed.
error: Unexpected token `[weak]`
  --> src/main.rs:31:14
   |
31 |             #[weak]
   |              ^^^^^^

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `Texture` in `gdk`
  --> src/main.rs:28:25
   |
28 | ...   let logo = gdk::Texture::from_bytes(&bytes).expect("gtk-rs.svg to ...
   |                       ^^^^^^^ could not find `Texture` in `gdk`


So I am trying to find a dependency with "gdk::Texture" and looked at crates.io, but have not found any dependency callout for this code.
I also performed a "cargo tree" and did not yield any clue as to what dependency I am missing.
Is there a way to find the missing dependency?

Are you sure that is the [dependencies]? Listing a package name twice like for gtk and gtk4 should be an immediate syntax error.

The (second) error is not complaining about a missing dependency, but rather a missing item within the gtk dependency - which the documentation corroborates that there is no Texture to be found there. Perhaps in an older version?

I removed gdk = "0.18.0" from cargo.toml and got essentially the same error message. I noticed that you mentioned "gtk" above, but the error message calls out "gdk". I am not understanding this process correctly?

I presume you're talking about this GTK example, it looks like the current master branch is for version 0.10.0 (from the top level Cargo.toml) and the latest published version is only 0.9.0 as you have. You'll probably want to either look at an older example or use a direct git dependency.

Yes, that is the exact example that I am working with. OK, thanks for the input. I will look for an older example and take another try at this process.

And sorry, you were right about my gtk/gdk slip-up, but again the documentation doesn't show a Texture :/

The documentation for gtk4 assumes that you install gtk4 like this:
gtk = { version = "0.9.0", package = "gtk4", features = ["v4_12"] }

which effectively leads to the gtk4 crate being renamed to gtk.
Because gtk4 re-exports gdk, this will also lead to gdk4 being "renamed" to gdk. Therefore the Texture in this case is actually the gdk4::Texture when you configure the dependencies like you did.
So you would need to change the line with the Texture to:
let logo = gdk4::Texture::from_bytes(&bytes).expect("gtk-rs.svg to load");

I would recommend sticking to their setup though and simply use:
name = "AboutDialog"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
gtk = { version = "0.9.0", package = "gtk4", features = ["v4_12"] }

as the only dependency.

I tried the modified dependency listed above and got an error The system library gtk4 required by crate gdk4-sys was not found. There was more to the error, but I am not sure how to list it as a comment here. Also got The file gtk4.pc needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory.

This is unrelated to the original question, but it seems your GTK installation is not complete: https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/book/installation.html
You also might need to adjust the features to match your local GTK installation as mentioned in the Project Setup.

Thanks frankenapps, I will look into that. Hopefully that is what I am missing.

When I run pkg-config the version is 4.6.9. Going to the AboutDialog directory and invoking cargo add gtk4 --rename gtk --features v4_12 and then in cargo.toml, setting the dependencies as gtk = "0.9.0" and running cargo build I get lots of errors such as error[E0603]: crate gdk is private. If I set the cargo.toml dependencies to gtk = { ... features = ["v4_12"] } then I get an error that contains this The file gtk4.pc needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory. I have found the gtk4.pc in the /pkgconfig/ folder.

@JimMosher Is it just me or do 4. 6 .9 and 4_12 not match?

Running cargo build gave me this error The file gtk4.pc needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory. The gtk4.pc is already located here: /usr/lib/x86_6-linux-gnu/pkgconfig. How do I update PKG_CONFIG_PATH to show the gtk4.pc here: /usr/share/pkgconfig
